# Determinado usuario redirecionar-se para determinada pagina

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite tenho uma duvida eu estou a tentar fazer com que um usuário da base de dados neste caso é o `adm` que se eu logar com o `adm` eu vou para uma página específica, neste caso um backoffice; sô que não estou conseguindo.

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else{
// Define $username and $password
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "company");
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = "SELECT username, password from login where username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row {
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Profile Page
}
mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection
}

?>
```

Comment: Olá Roman. Não coloque imagem do código ou sua pergunta vai ser excluída. Edite e apague a imagem e coloque o código digitado. Para formatá-lo selecione tudo e digite Ctrl + K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se te atende, mas de forma simples pode fazer:

```
if ($info['status'] == '1') { // verifica o valor de status no banco de dados
    //redireciona o admin para a dashboard administrativa
    header("Location: admin.php");
} else {
    //redireciona o usuário comum ao site
    header("Location: main.php");  
}
```

Comment: Sim, muito obrigado deu.